# How do I detect a WiFi Repeater on my network?

Tags: wifi, laptop, repeater

I work in a RV/Mobile home park in deep south Texas.  I want to know how I can find the person or persons using a WiFi repeater.  Is there a type of software or hardware (other than a laptop) that I could use?  If using a a laptop to detect a repeater, what would the repeater show up as?  Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Most access points can be configured not to allow a repeater. If the person was able to configure one you probably also need to set an administrative password on your router/access point and also configure WPA2 security.

Answer (score 3):

I have used Heatmapper and a laptop to find a mystery device in our office. [HeatMapper](https://www.ekahau.com/products/heatmapper/overview/)

If you have a map of the trailer park, you can walk or drive and map out signals.  Since you know where the known APs are, a strong signal in a location that does not have a park access point would get you close. Worked for me very quickly.